# Can I disable style definitions for specific elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working with someone else's code that has the entire site built on a highly annoying table structure with 100% width on every `<td>` element... If I had the time, I wouldn't ask this here and simply rewrite the whole darn thing, but it's a fairly large site and would take me weeks to rewrite, and I need the jquery plugin datatables to work. However, due to the entry `#container td { width: 100%; padding: 0; }` in the main style definition, the entire table is completely messed up :-(

So ... is there a way to get CSS to use these default definitions on all tables EXCEPT for `<table id="exception">` where it should ignore these settings and instead use the ones that come with datatables?

The problem is priority - datatables has the code `table.dataTable td { padding: 3px 10px; }` for example, and it is ignored because `#container td` has priority...

Again, as much as I'd like to, I can't mess with the original site structure at this time. I can edit the datatables CSS for some items, but I also have to remove the `width: 100%` stuff for this one table in a way that would STILL allow datatables to implement its own definitions...

I am using jQuery for one page on this site, so maybe I can use that to clear these definitions, but then that will also clear definitions set by datatables...

Thoughts (other than "don't use tables then")?

Comment: I think what you're looking for may be called a reset stylesheet. You can probably find one to reset a table and apply it to a scope above the items you want to reset.

Comment: Hm, maybe - but I still have the original site structure that has to remain active for the rest of the page...

Comment: If you apply the reset to a specific scope, such as a div containing just the datatable, it would not affect the rest of the page. e.g. `.resetTableScope table {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely you could just do that in CSS by tweaking it slightly (unless I've misread):

```
table:not(#exception) {
  /* Target all tables except the one with ID exception. */
}
```

There may be other slight tweaks that could be used, but that depends on the layout.

The [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) selector is supported in all major browsers, but not in older versions of IE (8 and before). 
One way around this is to use the [**Selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/) library.

> "Selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes
>   and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8. Simply include the
>   script in your pages and selectivizr will do the rest."

As you mentioned you're using DataTables, you're using jQuery, therefore using Selectivizr simply means including the `<script>`, and then `:not` will function in older versions of IE (6-8).

Comment: Huh, never heard about this before - cool! I could possibly do that. It would also take quite a while to edit the original CSS stuff to implement all of this, but if it's widely supported by browsers, I could give this a shot! ... except according to this, IE9 won't know how to handle it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not - unless this page is out of date or something...

Comment: @semmelbroesel Should be fine in IE9. I've provided a solution for IE8 and before in update

Comment: This might do the trick! Still a lot of work, but it would give me much more flexibility in the future while I continue to work with this structure... I'll give it a shot :-)

Comment: Oh, just realized that the rest of the site is NOT using jquery... I might have to do this, anyway...

Comment: @semmelbroesel But you're using DataTables? and by a lot of work, do you mean there are that many CSS selectors you'd have to change right?

Comment: Only on one page on the site... But I also just realized that I CAN simply add jquery using `<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>` - then the majority of other users (with other browsers) wouldn't have to worry. ... except what happens if I link the jquery file twice ... ? Nvm, I can use the reverse of the same code to NOT show the second jquery link for IE then. Thinking out loud here, sorry ;-)

Comment: Gah, this is infuriating... Maybe I have to test this in the actual CSS code and not in Firebug, but it's not working in Firebug - the actual site structure code goes: `#Container td { width: 100%; }`, and adding `:not` in there doesn't seem to make a difference (tried `#Container:not(.dataTable) td` and `#Container:not(#tbl) td`)... I don't much much experience with real-time Firebug style edits and don't know anything about `:not`, so am I missing anything here?

Comment: You need a space. The `:not` applies to a child element in your case. Without the space, you're applying it to `#Container`

Comment: Oops, @Zenith, missed one of your comments... Yes, I'll have to go through the original site CSS and find all table related entries and add the `:not` to it. ... Gah, I think I know why it's not working ... `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">` !!! Seriously, I am wondering if the original programmer was on drugs or something :-) Looks like I may have to run a load of manual `!important` hacks in the datatables css after all :-(((

Comment: The problem is the selector you're using. And you need to change that doctype pronto :p

Comment: Yea, I have `table id="Body"`, then `table id="Contaner"`, then `table id="Wrapper"`, ... and a few more before I get to the actual content. The whole darn thing could probably be replaced with just a few DIVs and be much more compatible towards the future without being stuck in HTML 3.2 ...

Comment: If I change the doctype, the entire structure dies - I've tried it in the past :-( I'm telling ya, I haven't seen code this outdated and thoughtless before... :-) I do very much appreciate you taking the time to help - even if we should end up not being able to do anything about it ;-) On one other site we had the time to replace the darn table structure, but right now I'm booked solid for a year ahead, so no dice...

Comment: Your selector would include the selector I used in my example not container:not, it would be something likec  #container table:not etc.

Comment: Tried that, too, but I'm guessing the HTML3.2 nukes it... And it might remove the definitions for the actual #Container table - but I bet I can't write `table#Container:not`, either...

Comment: Hm, I'm starting to wonder if it might be worth using an iframe for this one table *shudder* - I've never worked with one before, and I don't even know if it's a good idea or not - or if they can have their own doctype... Or if they work in HTML 3.2 (probably not)...

Comment: Ah man. I understand,  making stuff work in this situation would be very hard indeed. Consider unaccepting my answer in that case, hope you get the solution!

Comment: Heck no, I'll leave that answer as the solution because under remotely NORMAL situations, that would seem the perfect answer :-) Thanks so much for your help! And I'll just go and hack away at this ;-) Also, if all else fails, I'll load this one page in a separate window - done ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can apply !important to the table id="exception" css rules.

Comment: Same as with Dark Falcon's suggestion - it would prevent datatables from adding its own CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `!important`?

```
table.dataTable td { width: auto !important; }
```

Another way would be to make more specific selectors:

```
#container table.dataTable td { width: auto; }
```

Which should be more specific than `#container td`

Comment: I could do that, but I don't know what datatables does in its CSS code - if I did this, it would prevent datatables from making changes unless they work directly on the element level...